# Dynamically json value storing

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, getjson

Form a php page I am sending some value using json.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info");


    $i=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        if(is_array($row) && count($row)>0) 
        {
            $res['user_name'.$i]         = $row[1];
            $res['user_email'.$i]           = $row[2];
            $res['gender'.$i]           = $row[4];
            $res['i']                   = $i;
            $i++;
        }
    }

echo json_encode($res);
```

I have no problem with this code.But in another page I want to get that data code follows

```
    $.post(urlName, function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( data );
    $noOfUser   = obj.i;
    alert("No of user- "+$noOfUser);

    for($i=0;$i<=$noOfUser;$i++)
    {
    $user_name = obj.user_name+$i;
    $user_emai = obj.user_email+$i;
    $gender    = obj.gender+$i;

    alert("User Name- "+$user_name);
    alert("User Email- "+$user_emai);
    alert("User Gender- "+$gender);
    }
    });
```

But the problem is when I am adding this `obj.user_name+$i` instead of simple `obj.user_name` it can't retrieve the data properly but I need to get those value how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do attempts to get the `user_name` member of `obj` and appending the value of `$i`. Since `user_name` is not defined, the script fails.

This is because in javascript to access a member of an object using a dynamically generated key you must use the `[]` accessor, so in your case, the following example should work.

```
$user_name = obj['user_name' + $i];
```

Comment: If I put `$user_name = obj.user_name1;` I get 1st user name if I put `$user_name = obj.user_name2;` I get 2nd I just want to get this automatically by adding this `$i`.